# Observable collection - CollectionChanged Binding

Tags: c#-4.0, binding, collections, inotifycollectionchanged

During programming, I ran into the following questions:

1. Does a observable collection implement a CollectionChanged event by itself? (Because of differentbooks refering to the fact that it does, but google shows otherwise)
2. I have the following code, and I want my UI to update by binding (the code is for windowsPhone 7.1) Also, the binding works for single items in my observable collection, but when I try to add a new object to my collection, the CollectionChanged event doesn't fire.

   namespace Phone.lib.ViewModel
   {
       public class DeviceViewModel : ViewModelBase
       {

   ```
       DeviceModelInfo InfoList = new DeviceModelInfo();

       public DeviceViewModel()
       {
       }

       public DeviceViewModel(int index)
       {
           // Here I add a new item to the collection, But the ui only shows: Beckhoff, ver....
           InfoList.Add(new DeviceInfo("name1", "name2", "name3"));
       }        
   }

   public class DeviceModelInfo : ObservableCollection<DeviceInfo>
   {
       public DeviceModelInfo() : base()
       {
           Add(new DeviceInfo("Beckhoff", "Ver. 1A2B3C", "Stopped"));      
       }
   }

   public class DeviceInfo : ViewModelBase
   {
       private string devicename;
       private string deviceid;
       private string devicestatus;

       public DeviceInfo(string first, string second, string third)
       {
           devicename = first;
           deviceid = second;
           devicestatus = third;
       }

       public string DeviceName
       {
           get { return devicename; }
           set 
           { 
           devicename = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("DeviceName");
           }
       }

       public string DeviceID
       {
           get { return deviceid; }
           set { deviceid = value; }
       }

       public string DeviceStatus
       {
           get { return devicestatus; }
           set { devicestatus = value; }
       }

   }
   ```

Note: The class inherits from viewmodel base wich has the Inotify changed interface in it.

Code from my Xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="WindowsPhone.View.Device_Page"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Phone.lib.ViewModel;assembly=Phone.lib"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!-- Static Resource area for binding -->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ViewModel:DeviceModelInfo x:Key="deviceinfo"></ViewModel:DeviceModelInfo>
    <ViewModel:DeviceModelSensor x:Key="devicesensors"></ViewModel:DeviceModelSensor>
    <ViewModel:DeviceModelActuator x:Key="deviceactuators"></ViewModel:DeviceModelActuator>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!-- LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Kremer app" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->


    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,6,0,0" Name="Device_ListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource deviceinfo}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="100">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=DeviceName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=DeviceID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=DeviceStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,138,0,0" Name="Sensor_ListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource devicesensors}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=SensorName}" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=SensorType}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,429,0,0" Name="Actuator_ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource deviceactuators}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="78" Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=ActuatorName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=ActuatorType}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

I hope someone is able to help me with this problem because i have been at this for like two days now.

Also, my apologies for my "bad" english, but english is not my native language

Cheers -Bart

EDIT: done a little test

I have run a little debugtest myself to see if the add operation adds to the right collection en therefor increments the count value

```
        public DeviceViewModel(int index)
        {
        // Here I add a new item to the collection, But the ui only shows: Beckhoff, ver....

        Debug.WriteLine("number of added items " + InfoList.Count.ToString());
        InfoList.Add(new DeviceInfo("1", "2", "3"));
        Debug.WriteLine("number of added items " + InfoList.Count.ToString());
        InfoList.Add(new DeviceInfo("1", "2", "3"));
        InfoList.Add(new DeviceInfo("1", "2", "3"));
        InfoList.Add(new DeviceInfo("1", "2", "3"));
        Debug.WriteLine("number of added items " + InfoList.Count.ToString());
        }
```

output:

number of added items 1

number of added items 2

number of added items 5

Edit 2 (19-03-2012)

Last friday I tried to get it working like you suggested. But somehow the XAML can't find InfoList, and I don't know why. Maybe I do something wrong in the XAML itself or in the code behind or in the DeviceViewModel. So here is what I have at the moment:

DeviceViewModel:

```
namespace Phone.lib.ViewModel
{
    public class DeviceViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public DeviceModelInfo InfoList  = new DeviceModelInfo();

        public DeviceViewModel()
        {
            //DeviceModelInfo InfoList  = new DeviceModelInfo();
            InfoList.Add(new DeviceInfo("1", "2", "3"));

        }

        public DeviceViewModel(int index)
        {

        }
    }

    public class DeviceModelInfo : ObservableCollection<DeviceInfo>
    {
        public DeviceModelInfo() : base()
        {
            Add(new DeviceInfo("Beckhoff", "Ver. 1A2B3C", "Stopped"));
            //this.CollectionChanged += (e, s) => { Debug.WriteLine("event Fired " + e.ToString()); };
        }

    }

    public class DeviceInfo : ViewModelBase
    {


        private string devicename;
        private string deviceid;
        private string devicestatus;

        public DeviceInfo(string first, string second, string third)
        {

            devicename = first;
            deviceid = second;
            devicestatus = third;

        }

        public string DeviceName
        {
            get { return devicename; }
            set 
            { 
                devicename = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DeviceName");
            }
        }

        public string DeviceID
        {
            get { return deviceid; }
            set { deviceid = value; }
        }

        public string DeviceStatus
        { 
            get { return devicestatus; }
            set { devicestatus = value; }
        }
    }
```

The code behind the page:

```
namespace WindowsPhone.View
{
    public partial class Device_Page : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        private DeviceViewModel _DV;

        public Device_Page()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            _DV = new DeviceViewModel();
            DataContext = _DV;

        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedIndex = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
            {
                int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);

                //_DV = new DeviceViewModel(index);
                //DataContext = _DV;

                Debug.WriteLine("index:" + index.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The XAML code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="WindowsPhone.View.Device_Page"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Phone.lib.ViewModel;assembly=Phone.lib"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


<!-- Static Resource area for binding -->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ViewModel:DeviceViewModel x:Key="deviceinfo"></ViewModel:DeviceViewModel>
    <ViewModel:DeviceModelSensor x:Key="devicesensors"></ViewModel:DeviceModelSensor>
    <ViewModel:DeviceModelActuator x:Key="deviceactuators"></ViewModel:DeviceModelActuator>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!-- LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Kremer app" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,6,0,0" Name="Device_ListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" ItemsSource="{Binding InfoList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="100">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=DeviceName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=DeviceID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=DeviceStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,138,0,0" Name="Sensor_ListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource devicesensors}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=SensorName}" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=SensorType}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,429,0,0" Name="Actuator_ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource deviceactuators}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="78" Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=ActuatorName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=ActuatorType}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>

</Grid>



</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `ObservableCollection` implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface, which defines the `CollectionChanged` event.

2) When you add a new item in `DeviceViewModel` you do it to a new instance of `DeviceModelInfo`, so a different instance than the one you declared in your XAML

```
<ViewModel:DeviceModelInfo x:Key="deviceinfo"></ViewModel:DeviceModelInfo>
```

You have to either bind to the `DeviceModelInfo` instance in `DeviceViewModel`
or use the instance of `DeviceViewModel`, declared in your XAML

---

Edit

In your XAML you have 
     
That is the same as typing 'new DeviceModelInfo()' and then registering that instance in the resources of your control `PhoneApplicationPage`. And you bind the the `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox` to that particular instance.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource deviceinfo}}"
```

Now in your `DeviceViewModel` class you declare `InfoList` like this

```
DeviceModelInfo InfoList = new DeviceModelInfo();
```

You create a ***new*** instance of `DeviceModelInfo`, so `InfoList` is not the same instance/object as the instance/object in your XAML.

You must either
**1)** Bind your `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to the instance you have in `DeviceViewModel`. To do this you must first expose `InfoList`, that is make it public preferably through a property (but that's just convention, not required). Then make sure the `DataContext` of your control is set to the instance of `DeviceViewModel` your're working with. And then you can set the binding like this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding InfoList}"
```

Assuming `InfoList` is public

**2)** Get the instance `deviceinfo` created in your XAML like this:

```
DeviceViewModel deviceinfo = phoneApplicationPage.FindResource("deviceinfo") as DeviceViewModel;
```

assuming the instance of your control is called `phoneApplicationPage`. If you do it in the code behind of your control then `phoneApplicationPage` would be `this`.

And now you can pass this instance (`deviceinfo`) to your instance of `DeviceViewModel`.

From the naming I assume you're attempting to use the MVVM pattern, in which case you should go with **1)**

---

Edit

Making the field public is good enough.

Now you need to bind it to the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox`. Which can be as simple as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding InfoList}"
```

But this *requires* that the `DataContext` property of your page (`PhoneApplicationPage`) is set to an instance of `DeviceViewModel`. 
Without knowing exactly how you currently instantiate `DeviceViewModel`, it's hard for me to explain exactly how you can go about doing this. But I assume you instantiate `DeviceViewModel` in the code-behind of your page, so it looks something like this:

```
public partial class PhoneApplicationPage : Page
{
    private DeviceViewModel _deviceViewModel;

    //...

    public PhoneApplicationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // I assume you do something like this
        _deviceViewModel = new DeviceViewModel();

       // You need to set the DataContext to the DeviceViewModel instance you have created.
       DataContext = _deviceViewModel;
    }

    //...
}
```

Once you've made sure the `DataContext` is set to your `DeviceViewModel` instance then you can change the binding in your XAML like stated above.
So you should change the line

```
<ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,6,0,0" Name="Device_ListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource deviceinfo}}">
```

to

```
<ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,6,0,0" Name="Device_ListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" ItemsSource="{Binding ListInfo}">
```

Comment: @BartTeunissen, Exactly you declare an instance like so `DeviceModelInfo InfoList = new DeviceModelInfo();` which is a (new) difference instance, than the one you have declared and bounded to in your XAML.

Comment: Dear Simon,

First of all thank you for your reply. But you anwser doesn't work for me, also somethings are a little unclear to me aswell. Because you speak of "different instances" but if i'm not mistaken, the collection what i'm trying to alter is of the instance DeviceModelInfo, because when I declare the Collection I do so like this:

DeviceModelInfo InfoList = new DeviceModelInfo();

Also, I've done a little test myself. See the edit to my post. If you could add a little more detail to your previous explanation I would be a verry happy person indeed.

Cheers -Bart

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,

I get your point now, and almost everything is clear. The one thing I can't get working is making my:
InfoList 
Visible in xaml, and be able to bind to it. I made it public like you said, but i'm afraid i'm doing it wrong. I now do it like this:
Public DeviceModelInfo InfoList = new DeviceModelInfo(); 
 
If you could help me once more, it would be greatly apppreicated

Comment: I've tried to get it working last friday but the XAML can't find InfoList. I have editted my post above, it now includes the viemodel, codebehind and the XAML. Maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: He simon, i finaly figured it out. Although its not precisely as you explained it.

Thank you ;)